# How to set the minimum and maximum date for dayview?

Tags: swift, calendarkit

I want to show only current date with next 90 days.Not to enable other days.Also in scroll not to show the before start dates and after end dates.

How to achieve in calender dayview with start date and end date? Also disable the selection for other dates

Comment: Are you using this [CalendarKit](https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit)?

Comment: CalendarKit is not an Apple framework. You need to tell us what CalendarKit you are using before we can answer you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, that tag "CalendarKit" is used for this library only and is exclusive for StackOverflow: https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit

Answer (score 0):

Hі, this functionality is not available in the current version of the CalendarKit.

There are already a feature request / bug report available on this topic here:
https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit/issues/54

Feel free to comment there as well.

In order to implement this functionality yourself, you'll need to fork the library and change a few classes.